# Admin user shows "Sorry, you need permissions to view this content" in 2.4.4

Tags: magento2, 2fa

When I created a non-admin user with only few sections e.g. Sales , it after login, I will see this error:

"Sorry, you need permissions to view this content"

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As 2FA module is default enable in Magento, you have to tick the System > User roles > Permissions > Two Factor Auth.

After updated the permission, relogin the admin user and system will send a email for linkup Authenticator.
[image]